# Where is the Whomobile now?

Tags: doctor-who, props, vehicles

The [Whomobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_vehicles#Whomobile) was a strange-looking vehicle which appeared in a few *Doctor Who* episodes during the Third Doctor's tenure. It was the personal property of Jon Pertwee, and according to Wikipedia, it was actually registered for use on the roads, as an "invalid tricycle".

[image: Whomobile]

Since Jon Pertwee passed away nearly 20 years ago, I wondered what's become of his treasured and wacky vehicle now.

**What happened to the Whomobile after *Doctor Who*, and where is it today?**

Comment: Reported as given away (by Pertwee) to a fan who sold it at auction to a private collector of car and boat memorabilia for around £1200; http://tardisbuilders.com/index.php?topic=5137.0. It's been exhibited since, but rarely.

Comment: In the Whoville garage, behind the great big electro-whocarnio-flooks?

Comment: More like the Wheremobile.

Comment: @RogueJedi Who is the Wheremobile now?

Comment: The question asks where the Whomobile is out-of-universe; another interesting question is, where in the _Doctor Who_ universe is the Whomobile now?

Comment: @DougWarren I suspect that one would be less answerable?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Likely so, but you never know.  It's conceivable that it could have showed up in the background of a scene set in a UNIT warehouse or something.

Comment: River Song probably took it for a joyride and rolled it on some planet somewhere.

Comment: Recall this being brought to my former junior school in Nottingham by the chap who built it around the time it appeared in Dr Who.. Early 1970s
We all sat on grass verge part of the school yard whilst it was driven around the school playground by the owner who built the car. He built it in a nearby Garage. I recall seeing it appear in a couple of Dr Who episodes in the Jon Pertwee era..

Comment: When is the Wheremobile now is Who the question we should willhavebeen asking.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Privately owned by a man named Paul Buckland

According to a [2005 BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nottingham/features/2003/11/doctor_who_car.shtml), it was sold at auction in the 80s:

> So, what happened to the car? Well, it wasn't ever the property of the Beeb - the car was always Jon's. After the show it ended up on a trailer and was becoming a bit of a burden. In the end it was put in a car auction in the early 1980s and was bought - for £1700 - by someone who was purchasing the car for his son. The car is now in a secure location in the UK and hasn't seen the light of day since 1996.

One of the car's rare appearances was in the 1993 documentary [*30 Years in the TARDIS*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0175926/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1); Buckland was thanked in [the credits](https://youtu.be/4QNF0vuHyGw?t=2m45s) for providing the vehicle:

[image]

It's most recent appearance was at [a 2015 model show](http://www.hamex.co.uk/smallspace/smallspace%204/smallspace-4.html) in Hanslope, England, apparently still in the hands of Buckland (later images on the page identify him as the gentleman in the grey shirt):

[image]

In a video of the car's unveiling, [posted to Facebook by an attendee](https://www.facebook.com/brian.coombes.16/videos/10205927623367568/), show organizer Mat Irvine<sup>1</sup> introduced the current owners as Paul Buckland and another man (whose name I can't make out from the video).

I've [read](http://www.retrothing.com/2010/08/the-fate-of-the-whomobile.html) it [claimed](http://tardisbuilders.com/index.php?topic=5137.0) that Pertwee gifted the car to a fan at some point after he left the show, but I've been unable to find a more official source for that.

---

<sup>1</sup> As an interesting aside, Irvine was a visual effects designer for the BBC for a number of years, and built several of the K-9 props (including the original one used in "[The Invisible Enemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invisible_Enemy_(Doctor_Who))")

Comment: Wow was it really that long ago that we freed the whomobile from it's lair.I'm still hoping that it will be renovated.